# C#, dynamic generation of Struct and Enum in an .Net Assembly

Tags: c#, enums, code-generation, .net-assembly, typebuilder

Brief: I have generated dynamically many Enums and saved them in an dynamic Assembly.
I have tried to load this Assembly and use its Types(Enums) as Fields of generated struct. Those structs will be save in a diiferent assembly.

But there is a problem during the save-process of the new Assembly(of Structs)

Here is the code I actually use:

```
    public List<Type> CreateEnum()
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

        AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("AssemblyTest");
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

         for (int i = 0; i < list_Datatype_Typ.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list_SingleValues != null && list_SingleValues[i] != "")
            {
                if (tmp == eb_count)
                {
                    list_enumBuilder.Add( moduleBuilder.DefineEnum(list_Datatype_Id[i].ToString(),          // record a new Enum in the Module (Assembly, contains only one module)
                                                  TypeAttributes.Public, list_RealDatatype[i]) );
                    tmp++;  // variable to check if the previous Enum is completed
                }
                // Check if is a SingleValue
                if ((((i < list_Datatype_Id.Count - 1) && (list_Datatype_Id[i] == list_Datatype_Id[i + 1]))
                    || ((i > 0) && list_Datatype_Id[i] == list_Datatype_Id[i - 1]))
                    && (list_Datatype_Typ[i].ToString() != "ValueRange" && list_Datatype_Typ[i].ToString() != "RecordValueRange" && list_Datatype_Typ[i].ToString() != "none"))
                {
                    list_enumBuilder[eb_count].DefineLiteral(list_Datatype_Typ[i].ToString(), Convert.ChangeType(list_SingleValues[i].ToString(), list_RealDatatype[i]));

                    // check if those singlevalues with this type were all written
                    if (((i < list_Datatype_Id.Count-1) && list_Datatype_Id[i] != list_Datatype_Id[i+1]) || (i == list_Datatype_Id.Count - 1))
                    {
                        // Create the type and save the assembly.
                        list_EnumType.Add(list_enumBuilder[eb_count].CreateType());
                        eb_count++;                                                                         // At the end of an Enum... let's increment the  EnumBuilder_count
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        assemblyBuilder.Save(aName.Name + ".dll"); // Save the Assembly after all the Enum-Types were created
        return list_EnumType;                                                                           // return the list of enum-types
    }


    public List<Type> CreateStruct()
    {
      // Create assembly and module
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("AssemblyLeuze_Record");
        var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.
            DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.
            DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name, assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

        // Find MarshalAsAttribute's constructor by signature, then invoke
        var ctorParameters = new Type[] { typeof(UnmanagedType) };
        var ctorInfo = typeof(MarshalAsAttribute).GetConstructor(ctorParameters);

        var fields = typeof(MarshalAsAttribute).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var sizeConst = (from f in fields
                            where f.Name == "SizeConst"
                            select f).ToArray();
        var marshalAsAttr = new CustomAttributeBuilder(ctorInfo,
            new object[] { UnmanagedType.ByValTStr }, sizeConst, new object[] { 5 });


        //**************************************************************************************
        // Using the Enums.. to test ********************************************
        Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("AssemblyLeuze.dll");
        //Type a = ass.GetType("DT_0_29");
        Enum enumObj = (Enum)Activator.CreateInstance(ass.GetType("DT_0_29"));
        //enumObj i;
        string[] enums = (from type in ass.GetTypes()                                                   // get all the Enum-Names (will use it down in the conditions)              
                        select type.Name).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < list_Datatype.Count; i++)                                      // Read only recordT datatypes
        {
            // get all the RecordTs
            if (list_Datatype != null && list_Datatype[i] != "" && Convert.ToBoolean(list_IsRecordItem[i].ToString()))
            {
                if (tmp == tb_count)    
                {
                    // Open a new Type for definition
                    list_typeBuilder.Add( moduleBuilder.DefineType(list_Datatype_Id[i].ToString(), 
                                                                    TypeAttributes.Public |
                                                                    TypeAttributes.Sealed |
                                                                    TypeAttributes.ExplicitLayout |
                                                                    TypeAttributes.Serializable |
                                                                    TypeAttributes.AnsiClass,
                                                                    typeof(ValueType)) );
                    tmp++;  // variable to check if the previous Enum is completed
                }

                // Record the Fields

                if (Other Types)                            // Because of the order in the dataTable, read Datatype_Id instead of Datatype_Typ
                {
                    // ...
                }  
                else if (!(enums.Contains<string>(list_Datatype_Id[i].ToString())))
                {
                    list_FieldBuilder.Add(list_typeBuilder[tb_count].DefineField(
                                    list_Datatype_Id[i],                                        // the name of the struct-Feld
                                    list_RealDatatype[i],                                       // the datatype of the struct-Feld
                                    FieldAttributes.Public));
                    list_FieldBuilder[fb_count].SetCustomAttribute(marshalAsAttr);
                    list_FieldBuilder[fb_count].SetOffset(fb_count);
                }
                fb_count++;                                                                     // first incrementaton of fb_count

                // check if those singlevalues with this type were all written
                if (((i < list_Datatype.Count-1) && list_Datatype[i] != list_Datatype[i+1]) || (i == list_Datatype.Count-1))
                {
                    list_StructType.Add(list_typeBuilder[tb_count].CreateType());               // Create the type and save the assembly.
                    isVal.Add(list_StructType[tb_count].IsValueType);                           // true
                    fb_count = 0;                                                               // reset fb_count at the end of the struct
                    list_FieldBuilder.Clear();                                                  // Reset the list of Fields by clearing
                    tb_count++;                                                                 // At the end of a Struct... let's increment the  EnumBuilder_count
                }

            }
        }
        assemblyBuilder.Save(assemblyName.Name + ".dll");                                       // Save the Assembly after all the Enum-Types were created
        return list_StructType;                                                                 // return a list which contains struct-types
    }
```

Issue: "Here is the error message"

System.TypeLoadException: 'The type' DT_TTT 'of the assembly' AssemblyTest, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null 'could not be loaded because it contains an object field at Offset 1 that is misaligned or from one Overlapping field that is not an object field. '

I don't know if if due to and error during the loading, or my Assembly containing the Enums were wrong generated, or the is another way to generate those struct.

Thank you.

Comment: When creating dynamic assemblies, for debugging purposes nothing beats saving them to disk and have `peverify` check them and `ILSpy` (or another favorite decompiler of choice) to inspect them, ideally comparing them against something the compiler produced on its own. Diagnosing problems just by looking at the code that produced it is much harder.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert, thank you very much... indeed you are right. I first use "peverify but it could'nt find the errors". But after opening my dll file with ILSpy I found some Cast Error in my built Enums. I will try to correct it in my code now. Thanks one more.